# Динамическое создание view android

Tags: java, android

Мне необходимо создать `view` динамически, то есть не передавать при создании ссылку на статический `xml` файл, а динамически например передавая `String`, в которой уже хранится `xml` для `view`.
Пробовал сделать так:

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
xpp.setInput(new StringReader(text));
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(xpp,this,true);
```

Но, как написано на developer.android.com:

> For performance reasons, view inflation relies heavily on pre-processing of XML files that is done at build time. Therefore, it is not currently possible to use LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime.

Помогите решить этот вопрос и вообще возможно ли это?

Comment: Скорее всего вам это не нужно и ваш кейс можно решить другим способом. Вью можно создать программно без xml. Опишите, чего вы хотите добиться.

Comment: мне необходимо создать view чтобы потом превратить его в bitmap, для того чтобы потом распечатать по мапе картинку с устройства. Но мне нужно именно программно реализовать формирование xml в runtime и создание из него view

Comment: вам нужно пересылать не строку а идентификатор ресурса, например R.layout.main

Answer (score 0):

Стандартными методами такое не сделать, но судя по ответу на [enStackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21657847/5479247), есть обходной путь через рефлексию.
Там есть ссылка на GitHub с готовым методом, который создает "правильный" парсер для `xml` разметки.